# Android TableLayout Format

Tags: android, tablelayout

So I have a table layout that Im adding rows to through code since its not a constant table or a constant amount of rows.  The problem Im having is right now my last column isnt fitting all the text because the middle row is set to stretch and its taking up most the view.  Is there a way to set weights for the columns so that I can have the one row be bigger than the rest but still show everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem Im having is right now my last column isnt fitting all the text because the middle row is set to stretch and its taking up most the view.

Then either change it so the last column is the stretch column, or list both (e.g., `android:stretchColumns="1,2"`).

> Is there a way to set weights for the columns so that I can have the one row be bigger than the rest but still show everything else.

By listing more than one in `android:stretchColumns`, the stretching effect is applied equally to all. You can think of this as the columns having equal weight.

Comment: So I have that the problem is it stretches to match the content, and im trying to make it so it wraps the content onto another line

Comment: @DRing: Then use `android:shrinkColumns`, to indicate column(s) where Android should try to force word-wrap.

Comment: Perfect thanks just what I was trying to accomplish, just seemed weird to both stretch and shrink a column